# Running a Monte carlo simulation of a probit model on Stata

Tags: stata, monte-carlo, probit

I am trying to run a MC simulation for a probit model on Stata using existing variables. In all the examples I saw, the authors generate the regressors (generally only one) as well as y* and y=(y*>0) which makes it hard for me to get a better understanding on how to proceed in my case. How I understood the process is the following:

I had previously run my probit model

probit y $xlist

est store model1

And my codes for the simulation are as follows:

[image]

The problem is that when I run the code the values obtained, the results of the simulation only return
something like that:
[image]

No min, no max, just a constant.

In such a case, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code pulls out the coefficient/SE ratio for the variable in varlist 1000 times from the model1. It will be the same each time. It's not clear what you are trying to simulate, so it's not easy to know how to improve the code. I would try to put what you want into words, maybe using an example dataset like auto that everyone has access to. Also, it is much better to include code rather than a screenshot. When someone has to retype your code to help, it is less likely that she will compared to when it's a simple cut n' paste. Transactions costs!

Comment: Hi Dimitriy, I finally figured out how to proceed. It was my own misunderstanding of what simulation does. When I insert my coding the message that is being prompted is that I don't have enough space fr my characters.